# Chocolatey freezes during upgrading any packege

Tags: windows, windows-10, chocolatey

When I thy to upgrade any packege (as superuser) chocolatey stacks at the point of "Performing other installation steps" and starts to load one core of the CPU with no changing at memory usage and with 0 disk usage:

```
You have Firefox v109.0.1 installed. Version 110.0 is available based on your source(s).
Progress: Downloading Firefox 110.0... 100%

Firefox v110.0 [Approved]
firefox package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps.
```

When I stop the process Chocolatey tells:

`Exiting chocolatey abnormally. Please manually clean up anything that was not finished.`

and things that packege was updated and assigns the new wersion to it, but it reality is was not apdated at all

---

How I can fix or at least debud the problem further?

Reinstalling Chocolatey did't fix the problem

System restoration to previous point did't fix the problem

**Update 1:**
After eneblind debug and verbose modes it tells:

```
freenet v0.7.5.1496 [Approved]
freenet package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps.
Setting installer args for freenet
Setting package parameters for freenet
Contents of 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\freenet\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1':
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName    = 'freenet'
  fileType       = 'exe'
  url            = 'https://github.com/freenet/fred/releases/download/build01496/FreenetInstaller-1496.exe'
  silentArgs     = '/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SP-'
  validExitCodes = @(0)
  softwareName   = 'Freenet*'
  checksum       = 'd88d37d2e212bf87d9710bc10b1d07f508944e052e1825220ed50310d717261d'
  checksumType   = 'sha256'
  toolsDir       = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
}
Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs

Calling built-in PowerShell host with ['[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = '';[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ''; & import-module -name 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; & 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyScriptRunner.ps1' -packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\freenet\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1' -installArguments '' -packageParameters '' -preRunHookScripts $null -postRunHookScripts $null']
Redirecting System.Management.Automation.resources, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=ru-RU, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, requested by ''
```

**Update 2:**
[Logs (Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/wcTZivDH)

Comment: You haven't shared any logs or any troubleshooting that you have done (beyond reinstalling and system retstore).

Comment: @pauby which way of troubleshooting would you recomend?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may be related to https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1312#issuecomment-753559904

So force-reinstalling chocolatey-core.extension (I used latest: 1.4.0 and Chocolatey GUI 1.1.1.0) fixed the problem